# Does Space Exploration worth its price? Community wiki suggestion

Tags: discussion, community-wiki

We have here a [question](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/37496/1054) with the title

> How much did all the space agencies spent on rockets launching and space exploration? Does it worth it? What are the benefits for me and you?

This question is clearly opinion-based, thus it currently waits its closure.

However, we have the option to make it into (closed or open) CW post<sup>1</sup>, and I think this would worth its price. :-)

Later, this question could be used also as a reference in the future (similar questions could be closed as its dupe).

<sup>1</sup><sub>We only have the option to close it or keep it open. Technically only mods can convert a question to CW, but they will likely do it if the community thinks it should be.</sub>

Comment: I think that is exactly an example of what this meta question addresses: https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1331/26446

Comment: @DrSheldon In general, yes. In this specific case: now we have an option to collect Space Exploration arguments, what will likely have a good position in the google cache. Doing that, we use the SE essentially as media, this time as good media, to popularize the Space Exploration. It might be considered as an important long-term goal of the site by many among us.

Answer (score 1):

I vote no. SX.SE might be a good place to house separate broken-down questions used to support an argument for space exploration, but the overall question is too opinion-based to handle here--even with community wiki.

Comment: After a nice list of arguments were collected, a mod lock (or even a simpe community or mod closure) could solve this problem. On this way, both the goals of the CW post, and the site rules would be fulfilled.

Comment: @peterh I still vote no, but this is not a mod ruling, just a personal judgement. Others are welcome to hear your arguments and offer a different answer.

Comment: I think the way it played out is perfect. The question did have to be closed for the reasons stated above, but to the community's credit several reasoned, sourced and well-received answers were generated before the window closed.